# splash screen wont destroy on press of back button

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am fairly new to Android development and have just finished my first application for a university project. I added in a splash screen which works perfectly, it loads before the main menu and then switches after 3 seconds, however if the back button is pushed on the phone during the splash screen, you are taken out of the application then after the 3 seconds passes the main menu will be displayed. Is there any way I can get the application to be destroyed if the back button is pushed during the splash screen?

This is my splash.java file

public class Splash extends Activity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        Thread SplashTimer = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(3000);//3 seconds
                Intent menuIntent = new Intent("com.example.Main");
                    startActivity(menuIntent);
                }   
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                finally {
                        finish();                   
                }
            }
        };
        SplashTimer.start();
    }
```

}

Comment: You might want to give some code if you want to get help ...

Comment: Just FYI, splash screens are strongly discouraged in Android apps. 99% of the time, there is no reason to use one.

Comment: only reason i am using one is to fulfill my university requirements.

Comment: I did quickly earlier, but had to rush out so will try it out when back home and let u no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
     finish();
     return true;
 }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: i added this code to the end of my code. is that correct? just after the second form last curly bracket. if this is the right place then nah this didnt fix my problem, thank you for your help though

Comment: He stands before the last bracket. public class YourClass extends Activity { //your code ... //code keydown }

Comment: nah this didn't seem to work with my code. its ok i have just disabled the button so it cannot be pushed whilst splash screen is displaying. thank you for your response though, and im sure it was my coding rather than your fix that didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

This code should do that in a memory-leak free manner:

```
public class Splash extends Activity {

    private static final int SPLAH = 1;
    private final MyHandler mHandler = new MyHandler(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        Message m = Message.obtain();
        m.what = SPLAH;
        mHandler.sendMessageDelayed(m, 3000);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        mHandler.removeMessages(SPLAH);
    }

    private static class MyHandler extends Handler {
        private final WeakReference<Splash> mActivity;

        public MyHandler(Splash activity) {
            mActivity = new WeakReference<Splash>(activity);
        }

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            if (msg.what == SPLAH) {
                Splash s = mActivity.get();
                if (s != null) {
                    Intent menuIntent = new Intent("com.example.Main");
                    s.startActivity(menuIntent);
                    s.finish();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect solution for the question asked for.

Answer (score 0):

You can block or change the behaviour of the back button more easily (as of API 5 I think) by using this in your splash activity code:

```
  @Override
  public void onBackPressed()
  {     
        super.onBackPressed();
  }
```

Either comment out the super part to stop the back button closing your app or abort the thread with the time delay here before the super call.